# compiler warning: Double is not supported. Demoting to float

Tags: cuda

I'm getting the following message:

> Double is not supported. Demoting to float

I added the following command to the compiler : `-arch=sm_20` but im still getting that message.
im using sdk 4 with Nvida G105M.

What does this message mean?

Comment: I think what you're asking is pretty obvious, but it's usually better to be explicit.  Try something like "What does this warning mean?" or something of that sort.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The G105M is only compute capability 1.1 and so lacks any double precision floating point capability. You need a device with at least compute capability 1.3 if you really do need double precision, and even then it's generally not a good idea, as it tends to be a major performance killer on all but some of the newer, high end GPUs.

Comment: Oh, sorry. You are right about everything you are saying. But this does not answer his question. He is not getting that warning because he has a specific GPU in his computer. Read harrism's post.

Comment: OK - down-votes are generally for answers that are "not helpful" - I think this answer is still helpful even if it doesn't fix the immediate problem - it still addresses a more general problem that the OP will need to resolve. I will happily delete the answer though if it's not useful

Comment: Sorry for the down-vote i tried to undo the down-vote but it required me to edit your text. So i modified it by placing a line at the bottom :D and now the down-vote is gone ;). You are totally correct in what you are writing.

Comment: OK - thanks - I don't see any edit history though, and the down-vote is still there. Not that it really matters - I'm just curious sometimes as to why people down-vote.

Comment: While Paul R is correct about what compute capabilities support double precision, this is not the answer to the question.  The compiler has no concept of what GPUs are present in the system -- it only knows the commands and code passed to it.

Comment: @harrism: yes - I upvoted your answer and it should really be the accepted answer - I'mm loathe to delete my answer though as it still contains useful supplementary information.

Comment: I don't care which is accepted, and don't think yours should be deleted.  I made that comment to make it clear to future readers.

Comment: Could you explain " it tends to be a major performance killer on all but some of the newer, high end GPUs."? I have a GPU"Quadro K600"
  CUDA Driver Version / Runtime Version          5.5 / 5.5
  CUDA Capability Major/Minor version number:    3.0

Will the use of double decrease my computation speed? Why?

Comment: @luming: you need to check for your particular GPU how many DP execution units there are per SP. Older GPUs only had one DP unit per SP, so throughput was very poor for double precision compared to single precision, where there are typically 8 single precision units per SP.

Comment: What is DP and SP? I'v been looking for this terminology a while, but they all write in shorthanded form.

Comment: DP = double precision (i.e. `double`), SP = symmetric multiprocessor, essentially one CUDA "core". (Confusingly SP also stands for single precision, i.e. `float`).

Answer (score 6):

From your comment that you are using "sdk 4" I infer you are trying to compile an SDK sample.  The SDK makefile already contains a variety of -arch or -gencode command line settings for nvcc, so even if you add -arch=sm_20, there are probably other options on the command line that are causing the compiler to generate pre-sm_13 code, which is probably why it is warning.

Comment: Hey Harrism, im using a version of my own, the first output line that comes out when building a new version(after i insert the  -arch=sm_20) contains the  -arch=sm_20 property.. so i guess Paul R was right

Comment: harrism is totally right. You don't event have to have a Nvidia GPU in you computer in order to build your application.